# How do I union update two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, `df_original` and `df_update`, both with multiindex.

I want to update `df_original` with the values of `df_update` where keys match, and append any new data from `df_update` to `df_original`.

How do I do this?

(I've tried `df.update` and `df.merge` but can't seem to find a clean solution).

Comment: we might need some samples and the expected output to be able to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hard to answer without sample data sets but it looks like you are describing `df_original.combine_first(df_update)`.

Comment: @ayhan combine_first was the answer! If you submit it as a proper answer I'll mark it as correct! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description matches with the description of the [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) method:

> Combine two DataFrame objects and default to non-null values in frame
>   calling the method. Result index columns will be the union of the
>   respective indexes and columns
>
> Parameters:   other : DataFrame
>
> Returns:  combined : DataFrame

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 'x'), ('a', 'y'), ('b', 'x')])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3], index=idx)

df1
Out: 
     0
a x  1
  y  2
b x  3


idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 'y'), ('b', 'x'), ('b', 'y')])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([4, 5, 6], index=idx)

df2
Out: 
     0
a y  4
b x  5
  y  6

df1.combine_first(df2)
Out: 
       0
a x  1.0
  y  2.0
b x  3.0
  y  6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(df_original.merge(df_update,how="outer"))
```

I think this would work